# Changing the taskbar text without using SetWindowText

Tags: c++, winapi, taskbar

I know SetWindowText would set the taskbar text, but it would the titlebar's text also (to be the same text), and I want to have different texts for the titlebar and the taskbar. So I'm looking for a function that would change the taskbar text only.

By taskbar text I mean this:

[image]

Comment: I'd find that pretty much confusing... Especially if i have many instances of something open and click on one and something with a different name pops-up...

Comment: I want to show a percentage progress in the taskbar. That's redundant for the main window as it has its own progress bar control.

Comment: Maybe creating a hidden window and setting that as your main windows might accomplish what you want. You might have to forward all the messages tho.

Comment: On Vista+, you can use the `ITaskbar3` interface to show a progressbar on the Taskbar button without changing the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first paragraph in the "Managing Taskbar Buttons" section of MSDN page on [The Taskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144179%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) suggests creating an invisible window with the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` style that can be used to control the taskbar button and then creating a visible window that is a child of the invisible window that contains all of your content.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst you can do this by using a hidden window as your taskbar window, there are problems with that approach.  For sure it allows you to have different text in the taskbar from the text in the main window caption bar.  However, taskbar thumbnail previews, flip 3D etc. on Vista and up will show your hidden window which doesn't look very impressive!

Answer (score 0):

You can have your window style to none and re-create the title bar.